# Alert on chekbox button not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want show alert if checkbox not checked. this my code

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="kopi[]" value="Kopi-1>1</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="kopi[]" value="Kopi-2>2</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="kopi[]" value="Kopi-3">3</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="btn next">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name="kopi"]');
        $checkbox.change(function () {
            var $selected = $radios.filter(':notchecked');
                alert('no.3 not checked, direct to thank you page!');
                window.location="thank-you.php";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$radios.filter(':notchecked');` what is `$radios` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code:

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="kopi[]" value="Kopi-1>1</label><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="kopi[]" value="Kopi-2>2</label><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="kopi[]" value="Kopi-3">3</label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="btn next"><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name="kopi"]');
    $checkbox.change(function () {
        var $selected = $radios.filter(':not(:checked)');
            alert('no.3 not checked, direct to thank you page!');
            window.location="thank-you.php";
    });
});
```

Replace "`var $selected = $radios.filter(':notchecked');`" with

```
var $selected = $radios.filter(':not(:checked)');
```

that's all

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name="kopi"]');
            $checkbox.change(function () {
                if(this.checked){
                    // your code goes here
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$checkbox.change(function () {
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        var $selected = $radios.filter(':notchecked');
        alert('no.3 not checked, direct to thank you page!');
        window.location="thank-you.php";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name^="kopi"]');
    $checkbox.change(function () {
        ($(':checked').length < $checkbox.length) ? alert('no.3 not checked, direct to thank you page!') : window.location="thank-you.php";     
    });
});
```